# Assign image to product attributes

Tags: php, javascript, product-attribute, html

i have these codes to show product attributes on product page:

for drop down attributes:

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('stock_status') ?>
```

for other attributes:

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeName() ?>
```

i want to change these codes to show an assigned image instead of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your images with the same title as each of your required attributes/stock statuses, for example your images saved in some folder on your server, /media/chosenFolder/

Assign a variable to the attribute.

```
<?php $_stockStatus = $_product->getAttributeText('stock_status'); ?>
```

Then use php within an img tag to link to the image saved on your server.

```
<img src="/media/chosenFolder/<?php echo $_stockStatus; ?>.png">
```

Comment: when i use `<img src="/media/chosenFolder/<?php echo $_stockStatus; ?>.png">` the attribute image address is like this: `mysite.com/media/atticons/.png`.
and when i use `<?php $_stockStatus = $_product->getAttributeText('stock_status'); ?><img src="/media/chosenFolder/<?php echo $_stockStatus; ?>.png">` image address become lik this: `mysite.com/media/atticons/%D8%A8%D9%87%20%D8%B2%D9%88%D8%AF%DB%8C.png`

Comment: i'm new to magento,
how to assign it to attribute?
 its a drop down attribute with three value (soon, out, in)

Comment: I think you are assigning it correctly. <?php $_stockStatus = $_product->getAttributeText('stock_status'); ?> But it looks like your stock status needs to be decoded. You can try urldecode on the $_stockStatus variable. urldecode($_stockStatus)